# How to keep UITableView scrolling from interfering with my gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

In my iPad app, I have a screen with a scrolling UITableView in the upper right corner.

I also have a UIPinchGestureRecognizer attached to the overall app view. The pinch gesture works fine, but if one of my touches happens to fall inside the table view when attempting to pinch, my pinch never gets recognized because the table view is scrolling.

This behavior is totally understandable, but I'd somehow like the table view to defer to the pinch gesture. If table view scrolling were handled by a gesture recognizer I could just have the table call -[UIGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:]. But it doesn't, so I can't...at least, I don't think I can.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set delaysContentTouches to NO in your scrollView. The scroll view will still scroll but it should not cancel your gesture recognizer anymore.

Comment: It seems marginally better, but still unacceptable (e.g., interferes with the pinch gesture enough to make it unusable.)

Comment: I never figured out something better, sorry.